# using tinyMCE in Razor page

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, razor, tinymce

I am trying to implement TinyMCE editor on the razor page. below is the Model:

```
public partial class EmployeeInfo
{

    public int EmployeeInfoId { get; set; }
    public string? SignatureField { get; set; } = null!;
}
```

below is what I have in my view:

```
  <div class="form-group row">
              <div class="col">
            
                  @Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.SignatureField, new { @class = "form-control editorHtml" } ) 
            </div>
       </div>
```

Below is the jquery, I used, but does not seem to work:

```
@section Scripts {
        @{
            await Html.RenderPartialAsync("_ValidationScriptsPartial");
        }
      <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tinymce/4.0.20/tinymce.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            tinyMCE.init({
                mode: "specific_textareas",
                selector: "#SignatureField",
            });
        </script>
}
```

when I run the code, I just see an empty box where I cannot type anything. This is the rendered HTML :

```
      <div class="form-group row">
              <div class="col">
            
                  <textarea class="form-control editorHtml" id="SignatureField" name="SignatureField">
</textarea> 
            </div>
       </div>
```

any help will be appreciated.

Comment: I changed the case, still the same thing. Big box where I cannot type anything

Comment: Where have you placed the scripts? If they are in the view they should be inside`@section Scripts { }`. Btw I was wrong, `tinyMCE` also works it doesn't need to be lowercase.

Comment: I modified my script above

Comment: Copied your code to a local project and it works fine. Only had to change `EmployeeInfo` to not be partial because it was causing error in `@Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.SignatureField, ...)`, "An expression tree may not contain a dynamic operation". I can upload the project to GitHub if you want.

Comment: Can you please upload the project to github.

Comment: https://github.com/Jimmys20/SO75817635

Comment: Thank you! Its working now. In the layout page, I had this link: <script type="text/javascript" src="//tinymce.cachefly.net/4.0/tinymce.min.js"></script> and this was causing not to display the editor. Thanks for all your help! If you want to post your github solution, I will accept it as an answer.